# How to calculate the distance in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, euclidean-distance

let said I have two arrays of points, and I want to know what is the distance between each point.

For example:

```
array_1 = [p1,p2,p3,p4]
array_2 = [p5,p6]
```

p1 to p6 is point, something like [1,1,1] (3D)

the output I want is

```
output = [[distance of p1 to p5, distance of p2 to p5, ... distance of p4 to p5], 
          [distance of p1 to p6, distance of p2 to p6, ... distance of p4 to p6]]
```

what is the best approach if I want to use numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first arange the two arrays into an *m×1×3* and an *1×n×3* shape, and then subtract the coordinates:

```
delta = array_1[:,None] - array_2
```

Next we can square the differences in the coordinates, and calculate the sum, then we can calculate the square roout:

```
distances = np.sqrt((delta*delta).sum(axis=2))
```

Now `distances` is an *m×n* matrix with as *ij*-th element the distance between the *i*-th element of the first array, and *j*-th element of the second array.

For example if we have as data:

```
>>> array_1 = np.arange(12).reshape(-1,3)
>>> array_2 = 2*np.arange(6).reshape(-1,3)
```

We get as result:

```
>>> delta = array_1[:,None] - array_2
>>> distances = np.sqrt((delta*delta).sum(axis=2))
>>> distances
array([[ 2.23606798, 12.20655562],
       [ 3.74165739,  7.07106781],
       [ 8.77496439,  2.23606798],
       [13.92838828,  3.74165739]])
```

The first element of `array_1` has coordinates (0,1,2), and the second of `array_2` has coordinates (6,8,10). Hence the distance is:

```
>>> np.sqrt(6*6 + 7*7 + 8*8)
12.206555615733702
```

This is what we see in the `distances` array for `distances[0,1]`.

The above function method can calculate the *Euclidean* distance for an arbitrary amount of dimensions. Given both `array_1` and `array_2` have points with the same number of dimensions (1D, 2D, 3D, etc.), this can calculate the distances of the points.

Answer (score 2):

This answer isn't specifically for numpy arrays, but could easily be extended to include them. The module itertools.product is your friend here.

```
# Fill this with your formula for distance
def calculate_distance(point_1, point_2):
    distance = ...
    return distance

# The itertools module helps here
import itertools
array_1, array_2 = [p1, p2, p3, p4], [p5, p6]

# Initialise list to store answers
distances = []

# Iterate over every combination and calculate distance
for i, j in itertools.product(array_1, array_2):
    distances.append(calculate_distance(i, j)
```